# How to import scala library inside a regular scala repl?

Tags: scala

I am running `scala` on a script file and I installed `scalatest` in a local file

```
name := """codewars"""
organization := "com.codewars"

version := "1.0"

// lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0" % Test
```

But when I try to run the script via

> scala ./mumbling.scala

I get this error

```
./mumbling.scala:1: error: object scalatest is not a member of package org
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
```

Comment: sbt isn’t loaded by running scala directly. You need to use `sbt run`

Comment: hmm using htat i can't seem to run `sbt run mumbling.scala` and only test that one file.

Comment: This may come in handy https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scripts.html